# Python function won't return value from a list

Tags: python

I am currently having problem with the code below, take a look at it:

```
 def readData(fileName):
    inputFile = open(fileName, 'r')
    yearList = []
    locList = []
    line = inputFile.readline()
    while line != "":
        line = line.strip()
        year, loc = line.split("\t")
        yearList = yearList + [year]
        locList = locList + [loc]
        line = inputFile.readline()
    inputFile.close()
    return yearList, locList

def findLocation(yearList, locList, year):
    location = "Not Found"
    for i in range(len(locList)):
        if locList[i] == year:
            location = locList[i]
    print(location)

def main():

    fileName = input("Please enter the name of the file here:")
    yearList, locList = readData(fileName)
    print(yearList)
    print(locList)
    year = int(input("Enter the year you want the function to look for in the data:"))
   location = findLocation(yearList, locList, year)
```

Every time I run the code, It performs everything up to the findLocation function, where it does not return a value, but instead returns "Not Found". I have tried changing the loop around and tried indexes and stuff like that, but I just can not figure out why it keeps returning "Not Found" instead of the location. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Compare the type of the variable `year` in readData with that of `year` that you're passing to findLocation. I believe you will be enlightened.

Comment: As mentioned, `yearList` is a list of strings but you convert the year you are prompting for to an `int`. Keep the input a string.

Comment: thank you so much guys, greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
year, loc = line.split("\t")
```

You assign a string to `year` , and then append this string to your yearList.

But then, you do

```
year = int(input("Enter the year you want the function to look for in the data:"))
```

and assign an integer to your local variable `year`. What ends up happening is that you compare an integer to a string, e.g. you end up doing `"2016"==2016` which is `False` for every case.

In order to correct that, remove the `int()` function and work with strings only.